# UILabel UITextField UITextView

Tags: cocoa-touch

What's the fundamental difference between them?

Is a `UITextField` that's not editable is effectively a `UILabel`?

Are those essentially the same?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

- [`UILabel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel): "The `UILabel` class implements a read-only text view."
- [`UITextField`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield): "A `UITextField` object is a control that displays editable text and sends an action message to a target object when the user presses the return button."
- [`UITextView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview): "The `UITextView` class implements the behavior for a scrollable, multiline text region."

So:

- labels are read-only
- textfields are editable, and provide horizontal character seeking (not really scrolling) when the text is too long to display all at once.  Generally used to input short text.
- textviews are also editable, but provide vertical scrolling when the text is too long to display all at one.

Comment: How does that answer the question : "Is a UITextField that's not editable is effectively a UILabel?".I.E. is there any difference in rendering or behavior between a UITextField not enabled and UILabel.

Comment: THANK YOU for this..... you've saved 15 minutes of painful, deliberate research!!! :)

Answer (score 25):

In addition to the above answers, UITextView has selectable text.  This means that you can copy it or get the device to speak the text.

Comment: should have just been comment.

Comment: You can get the device to speak the text of UILabel too ?

Comment: @Petar, Amory means that the user can choose to speak the text themselves by selecting the text they want to hear and use the contact menu.

Comment: You can copy the content of the text field too.

Answer (score 11):

- UILabel - used for static text
  rendering,
- UITextField - is an input
  field,
- UITextView - is a multiline
  input field

Comment: Does that mean UITextView is effective UITextField with multiline enabled?

Comment: UITextField base classes are UIControl, UIView so it's can't be scrolled like UITextView. UITextView base classes are UIScrollView UIView. If I want a self expandable scrollable editor like text pane, i use UITextView. If i just want a simple input without scroll i use UITextField.

Answer (score 8):

Finally Apple have covered this part in this amazing talk:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/221/

The key takeways is as followed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also in addition to this: Only with UILabel you can get the Auto shrink feature, otherwise you should implement that (if needed)