# How to find out when UILabel wordwraps

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsstring, uilabel

I have created a couple of different `UITableViewCell`s for my `tableViewController`, this is because I have different bits of data I want to display depending what comes back. Because of this each `UITableViewCell` is of a different height.

This is all fine, However one of my `UILabel`s has to display a large `NSString`, so large that I have had to word wrap it onto a second line, The only issue here is that it messes up my `UITableViewCell` formatting.

My question is, is it possible to flag or capture some type of action when a `UILabel` receiving a `NSString` has to use wordrap because the size of the `NSString` is too long?

Or is there a way to calculate the physical length (not how many chars are in the string) of the `NSString` so I can decide hey I need to reformat my `UITableViewCell`..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way is to use sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: to get the size of a string. You use it like this:

```
CGSize stringSize = [theString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 3000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping ];
```

This is set for the full width of a table cell, but you would want to use the width of your label instead.

Comment: forget that.. I get it. lol I thought for some reason it was returning a string but i see its of type CGSize which i would just compaire to width of my UILable...

Comment: The website [iOS Fonts](http://iosfonts.com) is great for determining which built-in font you want to use AND getting the font name you will need to use in the `sizeWithFont:` method.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if i understand well but you have the height of your tableviewcell right? and you have a NSString maybe in a UITextView and this height of content of textview is higher then tableviewcell. Well, you should first calculate the content of UITextview, add into a list and when heightforRowAtindexPath was called, you should calculate new height (content textview) plus something... And to solve the max length you should count a limit for chars or limit for lines..

Some usefull code:

```
//resize height with content of UITextView
CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
frame.size.height = _textView.contentSize.height;
_textView.frame = frame;

//delegate textview to calculate limit for text.
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

NSInteger restrictedLength=140;

NSString *temp=textView.text;

if([[textView text] length] > restrictedLength){
    textView.text=[temp substringToIndex:[temp length]-1];
}
```

}

remember, you need to calculate the limit/size content from UITextview before heightforRowAtIndexPath called. When it called you already need to know your max height for cell.

Comment: Sorry if I did not explaine myself good enough. I have three different UITableViewCell in Interface Builder that are styled differently depending on the information recived. I was going to make another if the NSString I am passing to one of the UILabels is long enough to wrap. Then I will incorporate that new UITableViewCell with the double line UILabel into my project as a new UITableviewCell. So the only thing I need to be able to do is catch if the NSString's physical length will wrap onto the second line or not, then I simply define which tableviewcell to use... I hope that makes sense.

Comment: no problem. But why use an UILabel and not a UITextView? calculate the size of height of textview and then you can get how many lines you will have like this: numLines = textView.contentSize.height/textView.font.lineHeight;

Comment: also take a look with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040409/uilabel-uitextfield-uitextview