# How can I add the three dots of a UIlabel when the text is too long, at the middle of the text instead of at the end?

Tags: ios, uilabel

For example, I have the following two string:  **"How Munched is That Birdie in the Window?"** and **"S22 - E7"**. I want to present in the label the following: **"How Munched is That Birdie in ... S22 - E7"** If the string is too large according to the label's size and doesn't fit it". How you can see, the three dots are placed always in the first string, the second string is always shown full.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Set `lineBreakMode` to `byTruncatingMiddle` for your uilabel

Comment: Your question is leaving out lots of important details. Is this a label being setup via storyboard or via code? If by code, what language?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do it.

```
yourlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
yourlabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the UILabel's [ParagraphStyle LineBreakMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslinebreakmode) to [byTruncatingMiddle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslinebreakmode/1535410-bytruncatingmiddle), which will probably work in most cases with carefully planned label size. From the docs:

> The line is displayed so that the beginning and end fit in the container and the missing text in the middle is indicated by an ellipsis glyph. This mode is used for single-line layout

If you want to guarantee *none* of the "S22 - E7" string is truncated, you would have more control using two labels and setting layout constraints such that the width of the protected label is preserved so that it can display the full string whenever possible, but that is probably overkill in most cases.

You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14866912/2892227) helpful if decide to go a different route by manually manipulating the displayed string based on detecting how many characters will be visible given the width and font.